# how to redirect back to App with React.js from a component?

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router, react-router-dom, history

i'm new learner of React.js and i don't finding the right solution.
i have the CreateUser component and when a client success at creating one i want to Redirect the client to App...
i need it to happend in this function of CreateUser Component

```
private handleSubmit(e:any){

        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            username: this.state.username,
            password: this.state.password,
            confirmPassword: this.state.confirmPassword,
            userEmail: this.state.userEmail
        })
        this.passConfrim();
        if (this.isAlertVisible){
            console.log(this.state)
            this.myUserDateService.create(this.state);
---->                               ** Right Here i need to redirect!  **       <----
        }
    }
```

**in the end of the function at the if statement**

App:

```
import './App.css';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/LoginComponent';
import CreateUser from './components/CreateUser';
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { Router, Switch, Route, Link, useHistory as history} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {

  return (
    <Router history={history()} >  
                <nav className="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <a href="/Home" className="navbar-brand">
              To Do List
            </a>
            <div className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to={"/Login"} className="nav-link">
                Login
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to={"/CreateUser"} className="nav-link">
                Create User
                </Link>
              </li>
            </div>
          </nav>
            <div id="App-content">
            <Switch >
                <Route exact path={["/", "/Home"]} /> 
                <Route path="/Login" exact component={LoginComponent} />
                <Route path="/CreateUser" exact component={CreateUser} />


            </Switch>
            </div>
    </Router>
  );

}

export default App;
```

CreateUser Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { UserDataService } from '../services/UserData.service';

interface IState {
    username:string;
    userEmail:string;
    password:string;
    confirmPassword:string;
}

export class CreateUser extends Component <{}, IState> { 

    isAlertVisible: boolean = true;
    myUserDateService = new UserDataService();

    constructor(props: {}, myUserDateService:UserDataService){
        super(props );
        this.state = {
            username:"",
            password:"",
            confirmPassword:"",
            userEmail:"",
        }
    }

    private handleSubmit(e:any){

        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            username: this.state.username,
            password: this.state.password,
            confirmPassword: this.state.confirmPassword,
            userEmail: this.state.userEmail
        })
        this.passConfrim();
        if (this.isAlertVisible){
            console.log(this.state)
            this.myUserDateService.create(this.state);
        }
    }

    passConfrim(){
        if(this.state.password !== this.state.confirmPassword){
            this.isAlertVisible = false;
        }else{
            this.isAlertVisible = true;
        } 
    } 

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="form-group">
                <h1>Create User</h1>
                <form onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
                    <label >Username</label>
                    <input className="form-control" type="text" placeholder='Enter Username...' onChange={e => this.setState({username : e.target.value})} required/>
                    <br/>
                    <label >Email</label>
                    <input className="form-control" type="text" placeholder='Enter your email...' onChange={e => this.setState({userEmail : e.target.value})} required/>
                    <br/>
                    <label >Passowrd</label>
                    <input className="form-control" type="password" placeholder='Enter Password...' onChange={e => this.setState({password : e.target.value})} required/>
                    <br/>
                    <label >Confirm Passowrd</label>
                    <input className="form-control" type="password" placeholder='Confirm Password...' onChange={e => this.setState({confirmPassword : e.target.value })} required />
                    <div style={{color: "red", textAlign: "left"}} hidden={this.isAlertVisible}>**password not match</div>
                    <br/>
                    <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit" >Create User</button>
                </form >
            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default CreateUser;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need not pass history with Router instead you can use withRouter high order component from react-router.
Import withRouter inside createUser component - https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router";
```

Then we just need to export CreateUser component like -

```
export default withRouter(CreateUser);
```

Now you have access to all props related to routing inside CreateUser component, now you can use -

```
this.props.history.push('/your-route');
```

To check what else properties you have with withRouter, you can just console.log this.props.history inside CreateUser component.

Tip - You cannot use hooks inside class components, so you cannot use useHistory inside CreateUser component instead use withRouter.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `history.push('/yourRoute')` and that will take you to whatever route your heart so desires

Comment: i tried this solution but i got this error : ```Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app```

Comment: have you checked all those things?

Comment: what you mean all this things? i'm new with react if you can help me it's will be wonderful. i posted my code if you can check what i'm doing wrong ...

Comment: you need to look at the error message and see if you're breaking any of the rules. i.e. are you using hooks in the correct place? are you using 1 version of React? do your versions of React/ReactDOM match?

Comment: i call to useHistory in a react Component... the error maybe from this... but i looking for a way to use - useHistory for change path after client success creating a new user

Answer (score 0):

Since you are extending the user component from react, it is a class component and you cannot use 'useHistory' hooks inside it.

Also you are passing history as a prop to router, can you try the below code to navigate and let me know.

```
this.props.history.push('/yourroute');
```